# Resilience4j rate limiter allowing more requests than configured

Tags: rate-limiting, resilience4j

I have a simple REST API in my spring boot application on which I want to apply rate limit. I'm using Resilience4j rate-limiter for this.

My configs:

```
resilience4j:
  ratelimiter:
    instances:
      serviceA:
        limitForPeriod: 25
        limitRefreshPeriod: 60s
        timeoutDuration: 0
```

As per my understanding, this should allow 25 requests in 60 seconds, if more requests are received it will go to the fallback method without any wait or delay.

Command to hit the API:
`watch -n 0.1 "curl --location 'http://localhost:9080/api'"`

As per Kibana graphs:

[successful logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXw4H.png)

[fallback logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfluG.png)

There should have been only 25 successful logs in 60s instead of 50. Am I missing something here?